# Filter objects in xamDataGrid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, infragistics, xamdatagrid

Now a days , i work with infragistics xamDataGrid. my grid not contain simple primitive data types , it contain custom object ( object have 2 property code and description).
when i enable filter feature in grid it work well . but i found one error . when i filter object with equal , there is an object but result is empty . Please help me , this is critical issue .

i asked same question in  infragistic forum with sample project and image, please  refer this url to get sample project and understand my question. please help me.

[sample link](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/70873/358585.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To filter on complex types you need to implement IComparable interface in the class for your object.  Stefan Stoyanov posted an updated version of your sample [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/70873/362589.aspx#362589).